# postgres_fdw reduce data download during analyse

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, postgres-fdw

During analyse of foreign table I see a lot of `postgres_fdw` fetches on foreign server. For big tables it fetches all of it, even though it gives me 300 records in sample:

```
INFO: "test_table": table contains 59280698 rows, 300 rows in sample
```

I thought it will only send data that are used in statictic samples but it looks like the whole table is being sent to the requestor. I have tried to change the `default_statistic_target` for each column:

```
ALTER TABLE test_table
  ALTER COLUMN id SET STATISTICS 1
```

But it does not look to have any difference in fetches.

Is there any option to reduce network data I/O during analyse of foreign postgresql tables?

PS. I do not want to turn on `use_remote_estimates`. In `9.6.9` it corrupts the shared memory, in `9.6.17` it gives error on some queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ANALYZE` on a foreign PostgreSQL table will run

```
SELECT * ON atable;
```

on the remote table. The sample is created by applying [Vitter's algorithm](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~samir/498/vitter.pdf) to the result.

It might be an interesting enhancement to use `TABLESAMPLE` to retrieve only part of the table, but that is not implemented yet.